# pandas - are specific rows of dataframeA subset of specific rows of dataframeB?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes dfA and dfB like the following:

```
dfA = 
   entityId entityName property value
0         1        bob    propA     a
1         1        bob    propB     b
2         1        bob    propC     c
3         2       dave    propA    aa
4         2       dave    propC     c
5         3        bob    propA     a
6         3        bob    propB    bb
7         3        bob    propD     d
8         4       alex    propE    ee
9         4       alex    propF   fff

dfB = 
   entityId entityValid property value propValid  propId
0       123         yes    propA     a       yes  1
1       123         yes    propB     b       yes  2
2       123         yes    propC     c       yes  3
3       124          no    propA    aa        no  4
4       124          no    propC     c       yes  3
5       125    not sure    propA     a       yes  1
6       125    not sure    propB    bb       yes  5
7       125    not sure    propD     d       yes  6
8       126          no    propE    ee       yes  7
9       126          no    propF    FF       yes  8
```

What I would like to know is if what entities in dfA are exact matches with entities in dfB in terms of the property and value columns.

Would it make most sense to unstack the dataframes and express each entity in a single row first? The end result I am looking for would be something like this, however, any input about how to approach the problem is appreciated.

```
resultDf =
      entityId entityName  dfBEntityIdMatch  valid    invalidProps
0            1        bob  123               yes      ()
1            2       dave  124               no       (4)
2            3        bob  125               not sure ()
3            4       alex  '---'             '---'    '---'
```

Thanks  in advance.

Code to produce the dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',20)

dfA = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'bob', 'propA', 'a'],
                    [1, 'bob', 'propB', 'b' ],
                    [1, 'bob', 'propC', 'c' ],
                    [2, 'dave', 'propA', 'aa' ],
                    [2, 'dave', 'propC', 'c' ],
                    [3, 'bob', 'propA', 'a' ],
                    [3, 'bob', 'propB', 'bb' ],
                    [3, 'bob', 'propD', 'd' ],
                    [4, 'alex', 'propE', 'ee' ],
                    [4, 'alex', 'propF', 'fff' ]],
                   columns=['entityId', 'entityName', 'property', 'value'])

dfB = pd.DataFrame([[123, 'yes', 'propA', 'a', 'yes', 1],
                    [123, 'yes', 'propB', 'b', 'yes', 2],
                    [123, 'yes', 'propC', 'c', 'yes', 3],
                    [124, 'no', 'propA', 'aa', 'no', 4],
                    [124, 'no', 'propC', 'c', 'yes', 3],
                    [125, 'not sure', 'propA', 'a', 'yes', 1 ],
                    [125, 'not sure', 'propB', 'bb', 'yes', 5 ],
                    [125, 'not sure', 'propD', 'd', 'yes', 6 ],
                    [126, 'no', 'propE', 'ee', 'yes', 7],
                    [126, 'no', 'propF', 'FF', 'yes', 8 ]],
                   columns=['entityId', 'entityValid', 'property', 'value', 'propValid', 'propId'])
```

Comment: "What I would like to know is if what entities in dfA are exact matches with entities in dfB in terms of the property and value columns." But there isn't a 1-1 relationship between entities and values. So what do you want to compare? Do you want to find an entity in A that has the same *set* of values as B? Same *list* as values? Non-zero intersection?

Comment: since entity 1 in dfA has 3 property-value pairs: [ ( propA, a ), ( propB, b ), ( propC, c ) ], I am trying to see if there is an entity in dfB with those same property-value pairs. So if an entity in dfB has all of those and more, its not a match.

Comment: What if one has `[ ( propA, a ), ( propB, b ), ( propC, c ) ]` and the other has  `[ ( propA, a ), ( propB, b ), ( propC, c ) ,( propA, a )]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to get something similar to your expected output, at least on the data you provide. First create the column 'invalidProps' in dfB

```
dfB.loc[dfB['propValid'] == 'no','invalidProps'] = dfB.loc[dfB['propValid'] == 'no','propId']
dfB['invalidProps'] = dfB['invalidProps'].fillna('')
```

Now you can use `groupby` both dataframe independently and `agg` with different methods. You need to `sort_values` by 'property' and 'value' first if your real data is not in the same order between dataframe

```
dfA_g = (dfA.sort_values(['property', 'value'])
              .groupby(['entityId','entityName'],as_index=False).agg(tuple))
dfB_g = (dfB.sort_values(['property', 'value'])
              .groupby(['entityId','entityValid'],as_index=False)
               .agg({'property':lambda x: tuple(x), 
                     'value':lambda x: tuple(x), 
                     'invalidProps':lambda x: tuple(filter(None,x))}))
```

Now you can `merge` on 'property' and 'value' and use `fillna` to replace nan values, `drop` the unecessary columns and `rename` the one to keep:

```
resultDf  = (dfA_g.merge(dfB_g, how='left', on=['property', 'value'],suffixes=('','_'))
                  .fillna('---').drop(['property', 'value'],1)
                  .rename(columns={'entityId_':'dfBEntityIdMatch', 'entityValid':'valid'}))
```

and you get something like:

```
   entityId entityName dfBEntityIdMatch     valid invalidProps
0         1        bob              123       yes           ()
1         2       dave              124        no       (4.0,)
2         3        bob              125  not sure           ()
3         4       alex              ---       ---          ---
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much Ben.T